# No images displaying for me , just black boxes just white ticks

Tags: html, image

Im doing some coding in html , I have put in some image codes but they're not displaying for me. The only thing I am getting is a black box with some white ticks in it. Can someone please suggest how to fix this or maybe what the problem is.

Comment: Nobody will be able  to help without seeing any code. When requesting help with a code issue please make sure to try and post the code causing the issue and if possible an isolated sample of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I would add this as a comment but not enough rep yet :). If you need some help an example of your code would give people a better chance of understanding what your doing or even where you may be going wrong.

The answers people can give to this may not even help in your case.